# SEVERE: Error finishing response java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, tomcat

In catalina,out we getting below error and tomcat goes down frequently.

```
Feb 26, 2016 3:03:34 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor endRequest
SEVERE: Error finishing response
java.lang.StackOverflowError
                at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
                at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
                at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(InternalOutputBuffer.java:215)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:480)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.endRequest(InternalOutputBuffer.java:159)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.endRequest(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1784)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1126)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

we have already edit $TOMCAT/bin/setenv.sh, change the JVM setting as below but it does not help.

CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dfile.encoding=utf-8";export CATALINA_OPTS

Please provide your valuable inputs to resolve this issue.

Any help will  be appreciated...

Comment: I think there is some error in your code which calling again and again

Comment: There any setting using which we can avoid code looping or another solution to over come this error.

Comment: there may be some recurssive functions used in your code,check